# Please explain the use of spread operator in this case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, ecmascript-next

I have just started with reactjs and I came across this snippet while working on react databatle:

```
class MyTextCell extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {rowIndex, field, data, ...props} = this.props;
    return (
      <Cell {...props}>
        {data[rowIndex][field]}
      </Cell>
    );
  }
}
```

My questions are following:

1. `const {rowIndex, field, data, ...props} = this.props;`

As far as I understand this can be interpreted as

```
rowIndex= this.props.rowIndex
 field= this.props.field
```

and ...props will make sure it gets all the objects of this.props EXCLUDING rowIndex, field and data. Am I correct?

So my question is, isn't it would be better if instead of `...props` say, `...somethingElse` would have been used in order to make both 'props' look different.

2. In `<Cell {...props}>` what does ...props actually contain? All the objects of this.props or the 'remaining' ones other than rowIndex, field, data etc?

This is the link from where the snippet is taken:
https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. `const {rowIndex, field, data, ...props} = this.props;`**

This is an implementation of an ES6/2015 feature and a proposed feature:

- "destructuring" (http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingShorthandNotation)
- "object rest properties" a feature currently in proposal (see https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) which is being enabled via the babel plugin `transform-object-rest-spread`.

So to explain it clearly, the `this.props` object is being "destructured" into 4 new properties, namely `rowIndex`, `field`, `data`, and `props`.  With the `props` argument being the result of the "object rest" which gathers all the additional properties and puts them into a new object.

Therefore, your assumption for no 1 is correct.  `...props` will indeed contain all props other than `rowIndex`, `field`, and `data`.  The great thing about this is that you didn't need to know of or list out any of the "other" properties, they will be automatically bound into the newly created `props` object.

It's completely up to you on how you would like to name this, but I agree that "reusing" the name props may be a bit confusing.  Take it on a case by case basis.  I tend to name mine differently.

**2. `<Cell {...props}>`**

This is an implementation of the "JSX spread attributes" syntax (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html).

This will take all the properties in an object and then spread them over the target JSX node.

So for example if you had incoming props object of:

```
{ rowIndex: 1, field: 'foo', data: 'bar', message: 'hello', name: 'Bob' }
```

That would result in:

```
<Cell message="hello" name="bob" />
```

---

This kind of thing is really useful for when you create higher order components that wrap a component, but you don't want the higher order component specific props to be passed into the wrapped component.

Comment: 2 is still a bit confusing because in the next line, {data[rowIndex][field]} uses 'rowIndex' and 'field'. So I believe props here could mean the one containing broader set of objects

Comment: Don't confuse the two "props" objects.  There are two seperate instances, namely `this.props` and the `const props` instance that was created via the "rest parameter".  If this has confused you then def feel free to rename the `...props` to something like `...otherProps`.  Then the spread implementation would be `<Cell {...otherProps}>`.  Try playing around with the parameters and checking the output.

Comment: Are you familiar with how the destructuring argument works?  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: 1. Is neither *rest parameters* nor *destructuring arguments*. This is destructuring an object using *rest properties* (see: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread).

Comment: I was amending my answer as you sent this. :) Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: FYI, "object rest properties" is not part of ES7/ES2016. It's still just a proposal.

Comment: Note, #2 is not object-rest-spread, it is specifically a JSX spread property, which is JSX specific and unrelated, though similar-looking to ECMAScript.

Comment: @ctrlplusb Yeah I got it. You explained it really well in plain english. Thank you. Yes, I'd appreciate if you can further elaborate on how destructuring works. It'd be helpful for others as well .

Comment: @RahulDwivedi here is a great article on this subject: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth